# Remove Duplicate Record from XML file using XLST

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML file:

```
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
    xmlns:z='RowsetSchema'>
<s:schema id='RowsetSchema'>
    <s:elementType name='row' content='eltOnly'>
        <s:attributeType name='iBookID' rs:number='1' rs:writeunknown='true'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='10' rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
        </s:attributeType>
        <s:attributeType name='vchISBN' rs:number='2' rs:writeunknown='true'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='25' rs:maybenull='false'/>
        </s:attributeType>
        <s:attributeType name='vchEAN' rs:number='3' rs:writeunknown='true'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='25' rs:maybenull='false'/>
        </s:attributeType>
        <s:attributeType name='vchLCCN' rs:number='4' rs:writeunknown='true'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='25' rs:maybenull='false'/>
        </s:attributeType>
        <s:attributeType name='iNumPages' rs:number='5' rs:writeunknown='true'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='10' rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
        </s:attributeType>
        <s:attributeType name='vchPublisherName' rs:number='6' rs:writeunknown='true'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='75' rs:maybenull='false'/>
        </s:attributeType>
        <s:attributeType name='iYearPublished' rs:number='7' rs:writeunknown='true'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='int' dt:maxLength='4' rs:precision='10' rs:fixedlength='true' rs:maybenull='false'/>
        </s:attributeType>
        <s:attributeType name='tiPrimaryISBN_Flag' rs:number='8' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='ui1' dt:maxLength='1' rs:precision='3' rs:fixedlength='true'/>
        </s:attributeType>
        <s:attributeType name='vchDivision' rs:number='9' rs:nullable='true' rs:writeunknown='true'>
            <s:datatype dt:type='string' rs:dbtype='str' dt:maxLength='10'/>
        </s:attributeType>
        <s:extends type='rs:rowbase'/>
    </s:elementType>
</s:schema>
<rs:data>
    <z:row iBookID='3093' vchISBN='978-0-329-05967-5' vchEAN='9780329059675' vchLCCN='Not Available' iNumPages='317'
         vchPublisherName='FollettBound' iYearPublished='1987' tiPrimaryISBN_Flag='0' vchDivision='PLATALS'/>
    <z:row iBookID='3093' vchISBN='978-0-329-05967-5' vchEAN='9780329059675' vchLCCN='Not Available' iNumPages='317'
         vchPublisherName='FollettBound' iYearPublished='1987' tiPrimaryISBN_Flag='0' vchDivision='PLATALS'/>
    <z:row iBookID='3093' vchISBN='978-0-329-47925-1' vchEAN='9780329479251' vchLCCN='Not Available' iNumPages='317'
         vchPublisherName='FollettBound' iYearPublished='2006' tiPrimaryISBN_Flag='0' vchDivision='PLATALS'/>
    <z:row iBookID='3093' vchISBN='978-0-329-47925-1' vchEAN='9780329479251' vchLCCN='Not Available' iNumPages='317'
         vchPublisherName='FollettBound' iYearPublished='2006' tiPrimaryISBN_Flag='0' vchDivision='PLATALS'/>
    <z:row iBookID='3093' vchISBN='978-0-329-47925-1' vchEAN='9780329479251' vchLCCN='Not Available' iNumPages='317'
         vchPublisherName='FollettBound' iYearPublished='2006' tiPrimaryISBN_Flag='0' vchDivision='PLATALS'/>
    <z:row iBookID='3093' vchISBN='978-0-7587-0171-8' vchEAN='9780758701718' vchLCCN='Not Available' iNumPages='317'
         vchPublisherName='FollettBound' iYearPublished='1987' tiPrimaryISBN_Flag='0' vchDivision='PLATALS'/>
    <z:row iBookID='3093' vchISBN='978-0-7587-0171-8' vchEAN='9780758701718' vchLCCN='Not Available' iNumPages='317'
         vchPublisherName='FollettBound' iYearPublished='1987' tiPrimaryISBN_Flag='0' vchDivision='PLATALS'/>
    <z:row iBookID='3093' vchISBN='978-0-7587-0171-8' vchEAN='9780758701718' vchLCCN='Not Available' iNumPages='317'
         vchPublisherName='FollettBound' iYearPublished='1987' tiPrimaryISBN_Flag='0' vchDivision='PLATALS'/>
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

I have been working with trying to remove the duplicate records(rows) from it for a little bit now with no luck. I have read and tried several examples online but coming up a little short. If anyone can help me correct the syntax in my xsl I would be most grateful.

Here is my xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="z:row" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="RowsetSchema" >
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::z:row)">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result i am receiving is just the last record(row) is being written vs the 3 records(rows) I was expecting.

```
<xml xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"
     xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset"
     xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882"
     xmlns:z="RowsetSchema">
   <s:schema id="RowsetSchema">
      <s:elementType content="eltOnly" name="row">
         <s:attributeType name="iBookID" rs:number="1" rs:writeunknown="true">
            <s:datatype dt:maxLength="4" dt:type="int" rs:fixedlength="true" rs:maybenull="false"
                        rs:precision="10"/>
         </s:attributeType>
         <s:attributeType name="vchISBN" rs:number="2" rs:writeunknown="true">
            <s:datatype dt:maxLength="25" dt:type="string" rs:dbtype="str" rs:maybenull="false"/>
         </s:attributeType>
         <s:attributeType name="vchEAN" rs:number="3" rs:writeunknown="true">
            <s:datatype dt:maxLength="25" dt:type="string" rs:dbtype="str" rs:maybenull="false"/>
         </s:attributeType>
         <s:attributeType name="vchLCCN" rs:number="4" rs:writeunknown="true">
            <s:datatype dt:maxLength="25" dt:type="string" rs:dbtype="str" rs:maybenull="false"/>
         </s:attributeType>
         <s:attributeType name="iNumPages" rs:number="5" rs:writeunknown="true">
            <s:datatype dt:maxLength="4" dt:type="int" rs:fixedlength="true" rs:maybenull="false"
                        rs:precision="10"/>
         </s:attributeType>
         <s:attributeType name="vchPublisherName" rs:number="6" rs:writeunknown="true">
            <s:datatype dt:maxLength="75" dt:type="string" rs:dbtype="str" rs:maybenull="false"/>
         </s:attributeType>
         <s:attributeType name="iYearPublished" rs:number="7" rs:writeunknown="true">
            <s:datatype dt:maxLength="4" dt:type="int" rs:fixedlength="true" rs:maybenull="false"
                        rs:precision="10"/>
         </s:attributeType>
         <s:attributeType name="tiPrimaryISBN_Flag" rs:nullable="true" rs:number="8"
                          rs:writeunknown="true">
            <s:datatype dt:maxLength="1" dt:type="ui1" rs:fixedlength="true" rs:precision="3"/>
         </s:attributeType>
         <s:attributeType name="vchDivision" rs:nullable="true" rs:number="9" rs:writeunknown="true">
            <s:datatype dt:maxLength="10" dt:type="string" rs:dbtype="str"/>
         </s:attributeType>
         <s:extends type="rs:rowbase"/>
      </s:elementType>
   </s:schema>
   <rs:data>
      <z:row iBookID="3093" iNumPages="317" iYearPublished="1987" tiPrimaryISBN_Flag="0"
             vchDivision="PLATALS"
             vchEAN="9780758701718"
             vchISBN="978-0-7587-0171-8"
             vchLCCN="Not Available"
             vchPublisherName="FollettBound"/>
   </rs:data>
</xml>
```

Again I just want to eliminate the duplicate records(rows) in my new xml. I appreciate any recommendations folks may have. I am using the following online tool to test my xsl - http://xslttest.appspot.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it with a key,something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="DistinctEAN" match="z:row" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="RowsetSchema" use="@vchEAN" />

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="z:row" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="RowsetSchema" >
      <xsl:copy-of select=".[generate-id()=generate-id(key('DistinctEAN' , @vchEAN )[1])]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Shnugo, your solution also works great. I will most likely implement with the key recommendation. Appreciate the recommendation!

Comment: @RRyff, thx, glad to read, that you like this suggestion. As you are new to SO one hint: You tell Michael, that you like his solution. If so, you should vote his answer up. I'm not angry of course if you vote mine up too ;-) Just for your information: The acceptance brought 15 reputation points to my account, each upvote brings 10 rep points. By voting up, you can say "thank you" to each helpful contribution.

Comment: follow-up question if you don't mind. When I test with your recommendation with the online xslt Test Tool the xslt works find and output is what i was looking for however, when I put this code in a shell script I am receiving the following compillation error: 
XPath error : Invalid expression
.[generate-id()=generate-id(key('DistinctEAN' , vchEAN )[1])]
 ^
compilation error: file titles_isbn.xsl line 15 element copy-of
xsl:copy-of : could not compile select expression '.[generate-id()=generate-id(key('DistinctEAN' , vchEAN )[1])]'

Comment: I had to remove the at symbols on the vchEAN because it would not allow me to post the comment. However just so you know the at symbols are present preceeding the vchEAN field in the error message. Why would this work in the online tool but not in a shell script?

Comment: @RRyff, Are you sure, that the key is properly declared? Are you sure that the quotation marks you use to  encapsulate the full expression are others than the ones you use to  encapsulate the name of the key? If it is not that easy to solve please post a new question describing you problem with pasted code. Sure somebody will help you... And please do not forget to vote Michaels answer up (and mine if you want ;-)   )

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 'duplicate" is determined by the `vchEAN` attribute, you need to change:

```
<xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::z:row)">
```

to:

```
<xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::z:row[@vchEAN=current()/@vchEAN])">
```

However, I would suggest you do this by [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) instead.

Comment: Thank you Michael, your solution works great. Appreciate your time!